# How to send variable from function as prop to the child component?

Tags: vuejs2

I want to send one variable from function. I have function inside  methods in Form.vue from where I want to send variable "empNumber" to the child component Emp.vue

I tried to do it with props. But it didn't work.

Form.vue(Parent)
Inside

```
methods : {
    addEmp(){
      this.employees.push({
        emp_id : '',
        jan : '',
        feb : '',
        mar : '',
        apr : '',
        may : '',
        jun : ''
      });
      let empNumber = this.employees.indexOf(this.employees[this.employees.length-1])+1;
      alert(empNumber);

  }
}
```

Emp.vue(Child)
inside

```
export default {
   name: "EmpSection",
   props : "counter"
}
```

html

I want to passed variable be inside {{counter}} in Emp.vue template.

```
<label class="col-sm-4">
  Employee{{counter}}
</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your parent `html`/`template` section  you must include the child component so you can bind the data you want as a prop :

```
<div id="app">
...
<emp-section :counter="empNumber"></emp-section>
</div>
```

and that prop must be a data on your main instance (Form.vue):

```
data(){
 return {
  empNumber : 0 
 }
}
```

so your method now will become like this:

```
methods : {
    addEmp(){
      this.employees.push({
        emp_id : '',
        jan : '',
        feb : '',
        mar : '',
        apr : '',
        may : '',
        jun : ''
      });
      this.empNumber = this.employees.indexOf(this.employees[this.employees.length-1])+1;
      alert(this.empNumber);
  }
}
```